# How to compare two String hours and minutes with AM/PM?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to show my user whether the shop is open or closed when he checks the app.

I have stored (in Firestore) the opening and closing times of the shop as Strings.
As for the current time, I can get that from `DateTime.now()` then formatting that with the `intl` package.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();

String time = DateFormat.jm().format(now);
String opening = snapshot.data.get('opening');
String closing = snapshot.data.get('closing');


print(time);     // 9:49 PM
print(opening);  // 7:00 AM
print(closing);  // 1:00 PM
```

But now how can I compare those Strings in order to know if the store is open or closed at the current time?

Comment: I hope they are stored in UTC.  Otherwise, it's trivial to change the time my phone is showing (or just be in a different timezone) and get the wrong values for open and close.

Comment: The users and the shops they are following are in the same city and within hundreds of meters from each other. I won't be handling the case when the phone time is incorrect. That's on the user and this feature isn't important anyways. It's just a nice visual.  This is first time I learned a use case for UTC format :). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DateTime.compareTo()` method to compare 2 DateTime objects. It returns 1 if the DateTime Object is after[other], 0 if they are the exact same and -1 if the DateTime Object is before[other].

To compare the strings you can use `DateTime.parse()` method. Pass in a string and it will convert it to a DateTime. It takes plenty of different string date formats.

/// Edit

I would personally format the string with `DateTime.toIso8601String()` to make the formatting a bit easier, but it's up to you.

You could save your time with the `.toIso8601StringFormat` and parse it with the `.parse` method. To convert it from a DateTime to the string format described you can use this method:

```
static String dateTimeString(DateTime dt) {
   String dateString;

    var diff = DateTime.now().toLocal().difference(dt.toLocal());
    var todayFormat = DateFormat("h:mm a");

    dateString += todayFormat.format(dt.toLocal());

 return dateString;
}
```

Comment: The time format (1:00 AM) is invalid for the `DateTime.parse()`. If I can transform the time to a Datetime object, the problem is immediately solved, but I can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var now = DateTime.now();
var currenthour = (now.hour * 60) + now.minute;
int opentime = 9 * 60;
int closetime = 13 * 60;
String shoptiming = currenthour > opentime && currenthour < closetime
  ? "show open"
  : "shopclose";

print(shoptiming);
```

Comment: for utc use  var now = DateTime.now().toUtc();